# How to iterate through a list of URLs and make a GET request

Tags: python, api, gspread

I am trying to take a list of URLs from Google Sheets and then make an API request for each URL and return data in JSON format.  I currently am able to retrieve the list from Google sheets as well as make a Request for a single URL that I manually enter.

So far everything is working as expected.  I am more or less asking for guidance on what my next steps would be.  I am a novice in Python so not sure what to do next.

Here is an example of the output for the API request of the single URL in JSON:
{"date":"2019-02-07T00:00:00+0000","clicks":7},{"date":"2019-02-06T00:00:00+0000","clicks":7},{"date":"2019-02-05T00:00:00+0000","clicks":5}

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Dec  6 18:47:58 2018

@author: Dylan
"""

import requests
import json
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

#scope is just telling google what API you want to use because they have so 
many
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('Bitly Click 
Data-a892fb027ee3.json', scope)
gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)

wks = gc.open("Bit.ly Links & General Links").get_worksheet(0)
values_list = wks.col_values(2)

wks = json.dumps(str(wks))


print(wks.get_all_records())


url = "https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/bitlinks/THIS NEEDS TO BE THE URL LIST 
HERE/clicks"

payload = ""
headers = {'authorization': 'Bearer ACCESS TOKEN HERE'}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: What is your question? There isn't any info in what doesn't work, whether you get errors, what those errors are, etc.

Comment: It's been a long while since I used `gspread` but there was a transition in the Google API over authorisation. Please show the full traceback.

Comment: Sorry.  I just updated it.  I am not getting any errors.  I am asking for guidance as to how to do this.  I am a novice in python and not really sure what my next steps would be.  I have a list, but how do I replace the URL object with that list and then iterate through that list

Comment: You can't if you cannot access the API. Your question is about an authorisation issue?

Comment: I am not having an issue with authorization.  Let me edit post and clarify further

Comment: Right, I think we're getting closer. So, the sheet has a list of URLs, not `gspread`-related, and you want to send GET requests to each?

Comment: Yes sir.  The list is a column full of Bitly shortened links.  I need to retrieve the click data for each so I can import into Power BI and make a report off of it

Comment: We're fighting over edits on useless info that's in the code sample, and now you have included a JSON response. I appreciate you're responding to my comments but please take a couple of minutes to focus on the exact issue you're facing here and reformulate. Let's fix the target we're aiming for and not through hasty edits. If you've already retrieved the list of URLs from your Google Sheet then all of the gspread code is useless, start with that list.

Comment: Is something not clear about my question now?  The gspread code is not useless.  I need to make API calls every single day.  The list in sheets may or may not be updated.  Yes, I have the list right now, but what do I do with it?  I need to create some sort of loop and iterate through the URLs, but I have no idea how to do any of that, which is why I am asking for help